# apparmor blocking mysql start

Tags: mysql, apparmor

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and moved the datadir for my mysql server (retaining same ownerships and permissions) from /var/lib/mysql to /u/apps/mysql in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, then I updated /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld to include:

```
/u/apps/mysql r,
/u/apps/mysql/** rwk,
```

but get the error:

```
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
130906 13:55:31  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name .
InnoDB: File operation call: 'opendir'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

so I disable apparmor and it starts.  It looks like the directory it wants to open is '.' which I was assuming would be /u/apps/mysql but apparently is not.  Since changing the apparmor config it definitely gets further along but I have no idea what it's choking on.  Any ideas what's going on? Thanks...

Comment: have you changed the datadir directive in my.cnf ?

Comment: did you change ownership of /u/apps/mysql ?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify where I changed the datadir and that I retained same ownerships/permissions

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have permission issue on mysql datadir

```
  130906 13:55:31  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
  InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
  InnoDB: the directory.
```

Can you change the permission of datadir and also change the ownership to mysql. Once this is
done than give restart to Mysql.

Answer (score 1):

well I'm not sure why apparmor balked at "/u/apps/mysql/** rwk" when the original entry was "/var/lib/mysql/** rwk" and /u/apps/mysql was clearly owned mysql.mysql , but when I changed the setting to "/u/apps/** rwk" and it worked